# Powershell adding sequencial numbering in pscustomobject element

Tags: powershell

I've a `$List = @([pscustomobject])` with this values. The idea is to add a sequencial numbering in each element.

```
 Topic
 -----
los juegos
el arte
los animales
la mÃºsica
los juegos
la vida de antes
los juegos
el arte
la mÃºsica
la vida de antes
los juegos
```

How can i add a sequencial numbering each element ? Like this:

```
$List.topic

 Topic
 -----
los juegos_1
el arte_2
los animales_3
la mÃºsica_4
los juegos_5
la vida de antes_6
los juegos_7
el arte_8
la mÃºsica_9
la vida de antes_10
los juegos_11
```

Thanks for any help on this, I'm using this code

```
 $i = 1
 Foreach ($rt in $List){$rt.Topic = $rt.Topic{0:D4} -f $i++}
```

But the result is this :

```
los animales10:D4
la mÃºsica10:D4
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: Sorry, @Jeff, my bad

Comment: No need to apologise; just update the question to reflect your attempts, errors, and specific questions on correcting your stumbles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$list` is an array of PsCustomObjects, so just iterate over the array and adjust the objects  **property** `Topic` as you like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $list.Count; $i++) {
    $list[$i].Topic = $list[$i].Topic + "_$i"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So basically, since it's an array - we can modify its content. So:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $list.Length; $i++) {
    $list[$i] = [string]::Concat($list[$i],"_$($i+1)");
}
```

output:

```
los juegos_1
el arte_2
los animales_3
la mÃºsica_4
los juegos_5
la vida de antes_6
los juegos_7
el arte_8
la mÃºsica_9
la vida de antes_10
los juegos_11
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be $list.count?

Comment: Since I have dev background, I like to write Length for accessing the property of the System.Array class. 
And I do believe that Count property has an overhead for casting to proper class in order to access its property. Otherwise it enumerates through the array. 
TL;DR I just got used to it :)

Comment: `Length()`  refers to contiguous elements such as a *string*, where as `Count()` refers to the number of elements in a looser collection.

Comment: Plus one though, wasnt familiar with the `string.concat` method. Fancy stuff(:

Comment: Only thing is that it is not about adding stuff to the elements of a string array, but an array of **objects**